# Как запихнуть текущее время в переменную

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, простите за столь "тупой" вопрос, но вот у меня есть переменная и в неё надо запихнуть текущее время в виде "17.01.12. и 22.43". Это нужно в php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = date('d.m.y H.i'); // вопрос не тупой а, скорее, нубский...
```

Действительно была ошибка, не учел формат года при ответе ( зато, надеюсь, кагбы тонко намекнул на то что неплохо было бы спросить у гугла "php date" :) )

Comment: у вас кстати ошибка в формате :)

нужно d.m.**y** :)